# Write code list collection to string in c#

Tags: c#, string, collections, coding-style

HI all
I have problem when trying to convert list collection string to one line string.
But for each item i must edit with specific format.

Example

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
string result = string.Empty;

items.Add("First");
items.Add("Second");
items.Add("Last");

result = string.Join(",", items.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result); // Display: First,Second,Last
```

But I wish to convert to something like this:

```
[First],[Second],[Last]
```

or something like

```
--First-,--Second-,--Last-
```

I know there few technique to write this code using foreach for loop.

But could it write code just change all item in list collection into specific pattern string.

So the items collections string contain like from "First" to "\First/", or "Last" to "''Last'".

Regard

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question. I've read it a few times, and I'm still not sure what is the problem.

Comment: You can construct a collection of strings with an initializer list (though it might not match your scenario): `var items = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three", };`.  You also don't have to convert to an array to use `string.Join` anymore.  It now has an override with this signature: `public static string Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want a projection before using Join:

```
result = string.Join(",", items.Select(x => "[" + x + "]")
                               .ToArray());
```

Personally I think that's clearer than performing a join with a more complicated delimiter. It *feels* like you've actually got items of `[First]`, `[Second]` and `[Third]` joined by commas - rather than items of `First`, `Second` and `Third` joined by `],[`.

Your second form is equally easy to achieve:

```
result = string.Join(",", items.Select(x => "--" + x + "-")
                               .ToArray());
```

Note that you don't need to `ToArray` call if you're using .NET 4, as it's introduced extra overloads to make `string.Join` easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, this code what I looking for, more elegant to write it. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
var result = "--" + string.Join("-,--", items.ToArray()) + "--";
```

or

```
var result = "[" + string.Join("],[", items.ToArray()) + "]";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use join and then add characters in front and after as needed:

```
result = "[" + string.Join("],[", items.ToArray()) + "]";
```

will get you

```
[First],[Second],[Last]
```